# How to represent $y = ax^2 + bx$ using polar coordinate system?

Tags: polar-coordinates

How to represent $y = ax^2 + bx$ using polar coordinate system ? I want to find the length of the curve by polar coordinate system.

I've tried to $x\mapsto r\cos \theta$, $y\mapsto r\sin \theta$. The result is kind of weired.

Comment: $x\mapsto r\cos(\theta)$, $y\mapsto r\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: What do you want to do with what you get?

Comment: So this is an arc length problem?  Use the arc length formula for polar coordinates $s=\int_a^b \sqrt{r^2 + \left(\dfrac {\partial r}{\partial \theta}\right)^2}d\theta$.

Comment: @Bye_World, Thanks.  How could I  deduce this formula ?

Comment: The curve, in general (i.e., if $a\not=0$), is a parabola, so what do you mean by its length?  (@Bye_World, why use the coefficients $a$ and $b$ for endpoint values of $\theta$?)

Comment: @Bye_World, well done ! very impressive for such a quick response. Many thanks!

Comment: @BarryCipra Oops.  Right.  I didn't mean the $a$ and $b$ from his equation.  I just meant the bounds, whatever they may be.

Comment: @Bye_World, thanks, I wondered if you were just using the traditional generic symbols for upper and lower limits of integration, without noticing they were already being used.  So my question to the OP remains, what portion of the parabola is of interest?

Comment: @guanglei Start with the regular formula $s=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)^2}dt$.  $t$ is just some arbitrary variable that $x$ and $y$ depend on so change all the $t$'s to $\theta$'s.  Then manipulate $\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\right)^2$ (using the equations $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$) until you get $r^2 + \left(\dfrac {\partial r}{\partial \theta}\right)^2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra, Thanks for your comments. Actually, this question just helps me remind some basics, which means I am just interested in the integral method.